# A little problem in PDE or function analysis

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, elliptic-pde, calculus-of-variations

Let

- $E$ be the usual sobolev space $H^{1}_{0}(\Omega)$ on a smoothly bounded domain $\Omega$,
- $E_{k}$ be its subspace spanned by the first $k$ eigenfunctions of the Laplace operator, i.e.
  $$E_{k}:=\text{span}\{\varphi_{j}\in E: -\Delta\varphi_{j}=\lambda_{j}\varphi_{j},~j=1,2\dots,k \},$$
- $P$ be the positive cone in $E$, i.e,
  $$P:=\{u \in E~; u \geq 0 ~a.e.\},$$

Now set $P_{k}=P\cap E_{k}~~u^{-}=min\{u,0\}$.

**My question**: does it exist $C_{k}>0$, such that
$$\text{dist}_{L^{2}}(u,P_{k}) \leq  C_{k} \text{dist}_{L^{2}}(u,P)~\text{ holds }~\forall u\in E_{k}\; ?$$
or
$$\text{dist}_{E}(u,P_{k}) \leq  C_{k} \text{dist}_{E}(u,P)~\text{ holds }~\forall u\in E_{k}\; ?$$
or $$\text{dist}_{E}(u,P_{k}) \leq  C_{k} \|u^{-}\|_{E}~\text{ holds }~\forall u\in E_{k}\; ?$$
If not, could you please show me a counterexample? Thanks.

Moreover, this problem is raised from the proof of lemma 3.6 in "Infinitely many solutions to perturbed elliptic equations",[doi:10.1016/j.jfa.2005.06.014](https://pdf.sciencedirectassets.com/272601/1-s2.0-S0022123605X05468/1-s2.0-S0022123605002582/main.pdf?X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEIf%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FwEaCXVzLWVhc3QtMSJIMEYCIQCA3DmdTW7ToN5U0cdmubTTGzQJCXX38jpSYRu%2FaTQqOgIhANqGdebL%2FSXPmzKTqmmN0Xr%2F8itx2hkp7WGf6i72BrqTKvoDCBAQBBoMMDU5MDAzNTQ2ODY1Igz5FlE6QYbbcb7YH8kq1wMEn%2BjofTAgOGQ%2B7YALRJ5jJO286FtV2mHjiOBbpm1uIdXmNcC7GQJyghCxd4oRxfBUUIvPrbOwfdDH09ESAULHmDMXJNKlFyTF%2F33Jn2DSngmTTTq%2F8JFpuR2Bqe7p4k%2FDYnmnBm%2BMIsCoevLmtmJQ%2BNbL0bx%2FnvwCnvW%2BI45ClJddGgxdHCYBLrLxg0AOtNgy%2FIEagUE8CxkIXDro7QeNKau9lwQfEWrVa9lakzcMfXC70%2BnlVk2VzXAIdX2cKYDsf%2Fl8wl7Dkcs1%2FlqbbXNxz95n8CuAg7ifFqc0dfnetoIf02pLxKaw4hMx40lKKaWRdMLyKnT9C5fFToz5n%2Ff1liqy%2BDPvphnNV18lN7fZ%2Bbw5hUYj8q8rCxCIc8DnSeExbF78GjTXwR%2FsHHuHUZoXjIah2vK8SJUeVspjWfFK3CDxHokr%2BibxlkNhX2pjXIrZeAHqwMavPCT0bkvyU90XbZuI1vOc3h0FxnHfFXhyReh%2Bz6NjMl7OUv2YiaQgoxQEFRp4g2nNLau0RaPfxLTG77edF5nlL6b3bmSyu6KV%2FzWE2dOGEu9vk9cG%2F4ID3R1jUl8sSwEDiCMHZAaAMxjAld0l%2BtLwvKGq0046wxg5Uy9klhYCFbUwit2UiwY6pAHeFguTRVuilMp%2BddCPI10eVsY1ugttXA0kflCcFX73U8SfGzOTjmoheDKj%2FCNTQrzgGp8p4yhBjLvODQ8croHzoNyV6PoOl92rAARM5%2Fa9NOlTDvT2RTMpQzOI0sfSCvXEuUClp%2BrdylgeZJSLSMIT%2FQ6lyj12iGeJWZpoygEIvc3oTNdx8YjZSwbV4cv8smABlGArjB4p3eRWS0R5gFzpL8SZgA%3D%3D&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20211012T080454Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Credential=ASIAQ3PHCVTY4Y4CPKBJ%2F20211012%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=e9f461d9634a663aa1a87583e2578ad501f687454a69dff0e960c653c345a3f2&hash=ebaa2e2d930797073bf18eae43724b9df1cc260ef6f19e04102732392edbc536&host=68042c943591013ac2b2430a89b270f6af2c76d8dfd086a07176afe7c76c2c61&pii=S0022123605002582&tid=spdf-ca8bb609-0d0a-4a63-8c85-58d7098f6e09&sid=e27151265f16754ed3986a79985943117767gxrqa&type=client)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ruowq.png)

also see lemma 5.4 in "On finding sign-changing solutions",[doi:10.1016/j.jfa.2005.09.004](https://pdf.sciencedirectassets.com/272601/1-s2.0-S0022123606X05591/1-s2.0-S0022123605003319/main.pdf?X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEJ7%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FwEaCXVzLWVhc3QtMSJIMEYCIQDyfP9hsP1tHkBhbzcqwuQOpM51AhMSmUw8lQjARVyomQIhAL%2BkqkTXKKLwXuf08PPLGidPv2ZzyX2LYEMUTEyKhGbgKvoDCCcQBBoMMDU5MDAzNTQ2ODY1Igy%2F9ma67gic8nnsmhIq1wMLrIT%2FDxI9G6FQavBW3P21mCaVAw3de%2B4W15bgV7bTepA4sSaYvFGgm84PGZscT2JoxYpbJXPpHh%2FHncPeCKdSwMB6KisZ3qj3TUi5UVctygkh7PsrPp48LPms%2B98r%2FmEHdrrGD3PejQlZKrHT6eZ7S48OpXV7qtNt3FBqPGj12kZU3npDDdO4y3eOdo4vTyBkab7tyPAovwCr4frZiAooONzBayGkUEmKZ0bAnYgkElIXAgUbkGawBjFzPsfoiXmPsgX0GwiSIIV%2BBj4BEW4VglGabDqRtAO7xjGPegxoVM7chmabrwHwcOIuzT6pZhD4rqOeTjTtq88dBlRgUWVm3Ko6j%2BWDcfNVQxsbpgZZ3FjDKlJCt2Ki%2FKhBoET%2BC2CNNWMww8XJvT789JwPTI5MR7icHX5g54pxcbZV7iSgTrFHCUjE%2B%2BYyGg3cRNz73Wv65FvL1YnebwAeAGinMYhKSGPA5Vujv4f%2B3UrZM7TWOEK76t8ASgklluYS2B4hNdfNxMuhElgannyqfO8Mao2JVUcag5mBM1dJHcPc6xGbRgJQJkKG9AZ01CQ6trBMe9gCDy3ZSwRZAsgSu9xf0gr6%2BjjH8WzmMqoyE%2B7KLyqOS5i2ecsyQcgw%2F%2BaZiwY6pAEBkjdSZRAyQgflJe%2FR0CGWu1dHufRVHsGeRCeSEwzyfaBkii6sCmJv5IjB7QLnMiHrZYogDf4FdczVdD5ij%2Bp%2BL5Kd7q7FWkUAhLTx9Gm32EiH%2B4Nn8UO7Iczh0aMSuqPXdyec3P%2BRiF50K5bXrOKwo2fWF9nfUbGZMTFAh4UjeuIU1WD9OKgaIcMDNlMNzFMWJCUN4bS5AVZ1pV8UsBE5IpoaVQ%3D%3D&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20211013T062711Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Credential=ASIAQ3PHCVTYY3F5SIHU%2F20211013%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=74d463a3fdfe47d9fe039c0ce0d0c8d8647cae0dbe5669c7c1dd2f6fe8e6ddac&hash=4ab29c5d1d48cc6b4b9a75d0b843958d134747e1605579583d6db363c5a6e3b2&host=68042c943591013ac2b2430a89b270f6af2c76d8dfd086a07176afe7c76c2c61&pii=S0022123605003319&tid=spdf-9e5fb13a-6657-456c-a6e4-cfaa6bcc0bf1&sid=8b90046339b6054a78486f6-8787b72cf34agxrqa&type=client)
[image]

Comment: This is not Lemma 3.6 in that paper, but Lemma 5.4 not in that paper since it stops at section 4. The proof of Lemma 3.6 is different.

Comment: @username I  have corrected the wrong description , and these two papers are the same author.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first is not true, and probably also the others.

Take $L^2(0, \pi)$ and $u_1=\sin x$, $u_2=\sin (2x)$, so that $E_2=\{u=a\sin x+b \sin (2x)\}$ and $u \geq 0$ iff $a \geq 0$ and $2|b| \leq a$. If $v=\alpha sin x+\beta \sin (2x)$, then $\|u-v\|_2^2=\frac{\pi}{2} \left((a-\alpha)^2+(b-\beta)^2\right)$ and, if $v_\epsilon=\sin x-\frac{1+\epsilon}{2}\sin (2x)$, the closest positive $u \in E_2$ is $u=\sin x-\frac{1}{2}\sin (2x)$ and $\|v_\epsilon -u\|_2 \approx \epsilon$. On the other hand, $v_\epsilon$ is negative in an interval starting from 0 of length $\approx \sqrt \epsilon$ where the function is of order $\epsilon^{3/2}$ and $\|v^-\|_2 \leq C\epsilon^{7/4}$.

Comment: This is the right answer. But it's worth noting that all counterexamples are "like" this one, in the sense that they have $(u, \varphi_1) \geq c \|u\|_{L^2}$.

Comment: @user378654 Could you explain with some more detail what you mean? Many thanks

Answer (score 3):

This does not answer the question asked (see the other answer for a good counterexample) and I don't know if it's relevant to the paper. However, if $u$ is sufficiently far from $\varphi_1$, the first eigenfucntion, you do get a positive answer. Below I assume $\Omega$ is connected (you'd have to work out what happens more carefully if it's not).

First, we have that
$$
\|u\|_{L^\infty} \leq C(k) \|u\|_{L^2}
$$
for any $u \in E_k$; this can be checked for each $\phi_j$ and is standard (there is a clean argument with the heat kernel, or you can just apply the local maximum principle repeatedly on balls). Also, $\varphi_1 > 0$ on $\Omega$.

Now consider $u \in E_k$ with $\int u^2 = 1$ and
$$
\int u \varphi_1 = a.
$$
We have that
$$
\int |u|\varphi_1 \geq c(k)
$$
using only that $|u|\leq C(k)$ and $\int u^2 = 1$. Indeed, this integral is minimized by a piecewise constant function $u$ which is $C(k)$ on $F = \{\varphi_1 < t\}$ and $0$ outside of $F$, where $t$ is chosen so that $|F| = 1/C(k)^2$. Setting $c(k) = C(k) \int_F \varphi_1 > 0$ gives the inequality.

Combining, we have that
$$
\|u_-\|_{L^2} \geq \int u_- \varphi_1 \geq \frac{c(k) - a}{2}.
$$
Undoing the normalization, we have shown that for $u \in E_k$, if $\int u \varphi_1 \leq \frac{c(k)}{2} \|u\|_{L^2}$, then
$$
\|u\|_{L^2} \leq \frac{4}{c(k)} \|u_-\|_{L^2}.
$$
This implies both inequalities in the question in this case (the $L^2$ and $H^1_0$ norms of each side are comparable). In particular, it applies to any $u \in E_k$ orthogonal to $\varphi_1$, so to any eigenfunction $\varphi_j$.

Comment: Many thanks for the explanation. How do you see that the right minimizer is what you indicated?

Comment: Well, to minimize the integral you want to put all the mass where $\varphi_1$ is smallest. You can justify formally using the layercake integration formula $\int \varphi_1 |u| = \int_0^\infty t\int_{\{ \varphi_1 = t\}} |u(x)| d\mathcal{H}^{n-1}(x) dt$.